# SQL: How to design the database when one column has multiple categories?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to set up a database for a comic website. I'm planning to have:

- Table #1 : Comics (id, title, genre_id,...)
- Table #2 : Genres (id, name,...)

However, each comic can have multiple genres at the same time (romance, adventure, etc.).

So if I set up the database as above, I'll have to create multiple rows for 1 comic in Table1 which have the same other info:

```
(id, title,...)
```

but just have different `genre_id`.

This seems wrong...is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a many to many relationship table called genres.

This genres table stores all the genres that a comic book is a part of.

A comic book can be a part of multiple genres, and a genre can be a part of multiple comic books. This way, you can keep your comic book table normalized, without creating duplicates.

Genre_mapping table example:

```
comic_id genre_id 
1           1   
1           2
2           2
3           1
3           5
3           5
```

Genre table:

```
genre_id genre_name
1           Comedy
2           Action
3           Romance
4           Adventure
5           Thriller
```

Comment: What would be the advantages of creating a third table (comic_id, genre_id) vs. having multiple genres within the comic table?
`comic_id    genre
1    ['romance','action','fantasy']`
sorry i dont know how to format into a table in comment

Comment: I would suggest looking up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization which explains why database normalization is important.

Answer (score 0):

You want an *association* or *junction* table:

```
create table comic_genres (
    comic_genres id generated always as identity primary key,
    comic_id int references comics(comic_id),
    genre_id int references genres(genre_id)
);
```

You can include additional information in the table -- such as the date each row was created.